# React 16.13: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component in a child's event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, warnings, react-hooks

I'm using React 16.13 and I don't understand the workaround for resolving this warning. I am calling a setState function from a child component's event handler, which means the setState isn't being run on render. I believe this should be allowed according to the documents.

Anyone know how I can achieve this what I am trying to do in a way that plays nice with what React was intending to prevent here?
Codesandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-pike-zwvpb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

At the request of one comment, I'm also putting code here. Note the version of ant is 3.24.1 (but this is true of all version of Antd < 4). as you type the word cat, each successive letter is triggering the warning for me. Please excuse the ugly formatting as I didn't include the CSS.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { Select } from "antd";
const { Option } = Select;

export const getSelectOptions = options => {
  if (!Array.isArray(options) || options.length === 0) {
    return undefined;
  }

  return options.map(opt => {
    return <Option key={opt}>{opt}</Option>;
  });
};

const SelectWithSearchFilter = props => {
  const { value, data } = props;

  const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = useState([]);

  const handleSearch = searchTerm => {
    console.log(searchTerm);
    if (searchTerm.length < 1) {
      setFilteredList([]);
    } else {
      const newFilteredList = data.filter(item =>
        item.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
      );
      setFilteredList(newFilteredList);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Select
      value={value}
      showSearch={true}
      size="default"
      // loading={loading}
      // onChange={onChange}
      placeholder="enter something"
      onSearch={handleSearch}
      // mode={mode}
      // allowClear={allowClear}
    >
      {getSelectOptions(filteredList)}
    </Select>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SelectWithSearchFilter
        value="alligator"
        data={[
          "alligator",
          "bird",
          "cat",
          "cat2",
          "cat3",
          "dog",
          "cow",
          "monkey"
        ]}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code here? I'm getting a different error on your sandbox than what you are saying in your question

Comment: what error are you getting? I'll add the code in a moment

Comment: also, I do recognize that there are some other warnings first, but those are unrelated and being handled independently of this.